# How can I access jQuery widget options across files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing an HTML editor where the user can drag and drop elements from a toolbox to build out a page.

When the user drops an element, let's say a button, I want a panel to appear with all of the configurable options of that button (button text, color, border radius, etc).

Currently, and maybe this is wrong, I have all of these options are defined in a button widget.

I want to create a `panel.js` file that will be fed whatever element was dropped on the canvas, look at that element's widget options, and render the corresponding form elements into the edit panel for the element. So `panel.js` sees a button was added to the page, looks at `button.js` at its options, and adds check boxes and input fields to allow the user to customize the button depending on how those options are defined (boolean, string, array).

In order to do this, I need `panel.js` to be able to see/count the options defined in `button.js`.

How can I get a list of these options and know if their associated values are boolean, string, or array? Widget code below (which may be wrong...it's my first time):

```
$.widget('nt.button', {

    options: { 
        buttonText: "Button",
        isRaised: true,
        isPrimary: false,
        hasRipple: true,
        action: "alert('Clicked!')"
    },

    _create: function () {
        this._setOptions({
            'buttonText': this.options.buttonText,
            'isRaised': this.options.isRaised,
            'isPrimary': this.options.isPrimary,
            'hasRipple': this.options.hasRipple,
            'action': this.options.action,
        });
    },

    _destroy: function () {
        this.element.find('.legend').empty();
        this._super();
    },

    _setOption: function (key, value) {
      var self = this,
        prev = this.options[key],
        fnMap = {
          'buttonText': function () { buttonText(value, self); },
          'isRaised': function ()   { isRaised(value, self);   },
          'isPrimary': function ()  { isPrimary(value, self);  },
          'hasRipple': function ()  { hasRipple(value, self);  },
          'action': function ()  { action(value, self);  }
        };

      // base
      this._super(key, value);

      if (key in fnMap) {
        fnMap[key]();
        this._triggerOptionChanged(key, prev, value);
      }
    }

    _triggerOptionChanged: function (optionKey, previousValue, currentValue) {
      this._trigger('setOption', {type: 'setOption'}, {
        option: optionKey,
        previous: previousValue,
        current: currentValue
      });
    }
});

function buttonText(value, widget) {
    widget.text(value);
}

function isRaised(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--raised")
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function isPrimary(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--primary");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function hasRipple(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-js-ripple-effect");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function action(value, widget) {
    widget.bind("click", value);
}
```

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Why don't you let the button itself tell you what it got? Sort of like a getOptions method that returns an array of the names and value types of the options-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following approach:

Modified your `nt.button` a bit. Made changes in `_setOption:` like `var self = this.element` and in `function action(value, widget)`

```
$.widget('nt.button', {

    options: { 
        buttonText: "Button",
        isRaised: true,
        isPrimary: false,
        hasRipple: true,
        action: "alert('Clicked!')"
    },

    _create: function () {
        this._setOptions({
            'buttonText': this.options.buttonText,
            'isRaised': this.options.isRaised,
            'isPrimary': this.options.isPrimary,
            'hasRipple': this.options.hasRipple,
            'action': this.options.action,
        });
    },

    _destroy: function () {
        this.element.find('.legend').empty();
        this._super();
    },

    _setOption: function (key, value) {
      var self = this.element,
        prev = this.options[key],
        fnMap = {
          'buttonText': function () { buttonText(value, self); },
          'isRaised': function ()   { isRaised(value, self);   },
          'isPrimary': function ()  { isPrimary(value, self);  },
          'hasRipple': function ()  { hasRipple(value, self);  },
          'action': function ()  { action(value, self);  }
        };

      // base
      this._super(key, value);

      if (key in fnMap) {
        fnMap[key]();
        this._triggerOptionChanged(key, prev, value);
      }
    },

    _triggerOptionChanged: function (optionKey, previousValue, currentValue) {
      this._trigger('setOption', {type: 'setOption'}, {
        option: optionKey,
        previous: previousValue,
        current: currentValue
      });
    }
});

function buttonText(value, widget) {
    widget.text(value);
}

function isRaised(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--raised")
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function isPrimary(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--primary");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function hasRipple(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-js-ripple-effect");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function action(value, widget) {
    widget.bind("click", function(){eval(value)});
}
```

Now in your other code where you need to detect the button widget's options, following code can be useful:

```
var buttonOptions = $.nt.button.prototype.options;
        for(var i in buttonOptions) {
             if (buttonOptions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if(buttonOptions[i] != null)
                    $("div.options").append("<div>Option Name: <b>"+i+"</b> , Default Value: <b>"+ buttonOptions[i] + "</b>, Type: <b>"+ typeof buttonOptions[i]+"</b></div></br>")
            }
        }
```

Here `$.nt.button.prototype.options` will fetch you all options defined for your custom button widget. Just make sure that you load JS files in following order:
1) JQuery
2) JQuery UI
3) Your Custom widget `button.js`
4) Page level code which gets invoked on drag-drop of button widget.

Hope this will help you a bit.

```js
var buttonOptions = $.nt.button.prototype.options;


  for(var i in buttonOptions) {
    if (buttonOptions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       if(buttonOptions[i] != null)
     $("div.options").append("<div>Option Name: <b>"+i+"</b> , Default Value: <b>"+ buttonOptions[i] + "</b>, Type: <b>"+ typeof buttonOptions[i]+"</b></div></br>")
   }
     }


$(".mybutton").button();
  
  $(".changeOptions").click(function(){
   $(".mybutton").data("ntButton").option("buttonText","Updated Button Text");
   $(".mybutton").data("ntButton").option("action","alert('Newer action associated')");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.widget('nt.button', {

    options: { 
        buttonText: "Button",
        isRaised: true,
        isPrimary: false,
        hasRipple: true,
        action: "alert('Clicked!')"
    },

    _create: function () {
        this._setOptions({
            'buttonText': this.options.buttonText,
            'isRaised': this.options.isRaised,
            'isPrimary': this.options.isPrimary,
            'hasRipple': this.options.hasRipple,
            'action': this.options.action,
        });
    },

    _destroy: function () {
        this.element.find('.legend').empty();
        this._super();
    },

    _setOption: function (key, value) {
      var self = this.element,
        prev = this.options[key],
        fnMap = {
          'buttonText': function () { buttonText(value, self); },
          'isRaised': function ()   { isRaised(value, self);   },
          'isPrimary': function ()  { isPrimary(value, self);  },
          'hasRipple': function ()  { hasRipple(value, self);  },
          'action': function ()  { action(value, self);  }
        };

      // base
      this._super(key, value);

      if (key in fnMap) {
        fnMap[key]();
        this._triggerOptionChanged(key, prev, value);
      }
    },

    _triggerOptionChanged: function (optionKey, previousValue, currentValue) {
      this._trigger('setOption', {type: 'setOption'}, {
        option: optionKey,
        previous: previousValue,
        current: currentValue
      });
    }
});

function buttonText(value, widget) {
    widget.text(value);
}

function isRaised(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--raised")
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function isPrimary(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-button--primary");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function hasRipple(value, widget) {
    if(value === true) {
        widget.addClass("mdl-js-ripple-effect");
    }
    if(value === false) {
        return;
    }
}

function action(value, widget) {
    widget.unbind("click");
    widget.bind("click", function(){eval(value)});
}
</script>  


<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px red;">
  <div class="mybutton"></div>
 
 <div class="changeOptions">Click To Change Options</div>
</div>

<div class="options">
 <div>Button Widget has following Options:</div></br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is tremendous help, and gets me pretty close to where I need to be. One last question: Let's so I get the widget options panel displaying correctly with all the appropriate fields for the button options. How do I then write those back to the [button] widget on the page to "save" them?

Comment: Glad to know it helped you. I have updated the code snippet for answering your question. We can update button's default option on Panel "save" by calling `$(".mybutton").data("ntButton").option("buttonText","Updated Button Text");`. Please note that I have again made small change in your `function action(value, widget)` to unbind previously attached click action and to add newer action. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, vijay! Your guidance has been very much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure...Jon. Good to hear that this answer helped you to achieve your goal. All the best. :)